# Pulling all objects in the global environment that have specific attributes

Tags: r

Let's say I have a list of objects in the global environment. How would I pull only those that have a specific attribute set?

```
x1 <- 1:10
x2 <- 1:10
x3 <- 1:10
x4 <- 1:10
x5 <- 1:10 

attr(x1, "foo") <- "bar"
attr(x5, "foo") <- "bar"
```

How do I pull x1 and x5 based on the fact that they have the attribute "foo" as "bar"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way to do it

```
# collect all objects in global environment
all = lapply(ls(), get)

# extract objects with attribute = "bar"
bar = all[lapply(all, attr, "foo") == "bar"]
```

Answer (score 6):

A couple of variations on Ramnath's answer.

For getting multiple objects, it is preferable to use `mget` instead of `get` with `lapply`.

```
all <- mget(ls(), envir = globalenv())
```

You can use `Filter` to filter the list of variables. I think this makes the intention of the code slightly clearer.  (Though it does the same thing underneath the bonnet.)

```
Filter(function(x) attr(x, "foo") == "bar", all)
```